# Android Ion Cache Refresh

Tags: android, caching, android-ion

I'm using a specific url to obtain an image online, but the url itself automatically changes every few minutes.
I'm using ION library from [Here](https://github.com/koush/ion)
The problem I'm having is when I refresh the page, the page itself looks like it is refreshing but the exact same picture is appearing.
I'm assuming its a cached image? If I reinstall the application, then it obtains the correct image again.

This is how I'm using ION where imageID2[position] is just a typical url to a jpg.

```
    Ion.with(imageView)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .load(imageId2[position]);
```

Is there anyway I can disable the cache or just make it refind the images again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append a unique string to your url for example a current timestamp in order to force Ion to treat each request as unique.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any control over the url link itself unfortunately, otherwise that would be a great idea.

Comment: Sorry I mean locally when you make your call. Just append an imaginary parameter to the end of your url. e.g. "http://yoursite.com?uniqueid="+timestamp

Comment: Oh right, I would never of thought of that, haha worked perfect mate, thanks heaps!! Appreciated!!

Answer (score 7):

Use .noCache() to bypass caches.

Comment: I tried .noCache() but I seem to get a Cannot Resolve Method .noCache() error.

Comment: You'll need to use the longform then that lets you modify http parameters:

Ion.with(context)
.load(url)
.noCache()
.withBitmap()
.placeholder.error.load....

Answer (score 7):

As per documentation [here](https://github.com/koush/ion), use the "long" way to build an ImageView request so that you can add headers, noCache, etc.

Change your original request from this:

```
Ion.with(imageView)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .load(urlString);
```

To this:

```
Ion.with(context)
        .load(urlString)
        .noCache()
        .withBitmap()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .intoImageView(imageView);
```