# SmartImageVIew, I would like to force refresh (and not caching)

Tags: android, caching, imageview, loopj

I am using this useful class that allow smart online downloading of images (from the loopj guys).
It works fine, but i cannot force the "refresh" in the case of same name images that could have been changed in the server (example: I update my profile picture).
So at the moment I am forcing the brutal delete of my app cache dir before the setImageUrl().
It works, and some FileNotFoundException is raised. No big deal, but I hate having something that works "without really working", I don't know if you know what I mean :)
Lots of thanks, again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831544/764624)

It essentially involves appending a paramater to the end of the url you use to fetch the image and ensuring that the parameter is unique each time you call it thus forcing a fresh call.

Comment: such for example a timestamp? Great idea! I'll try tomorrow first thing.

Comment: Well wait, you mean an external parameter or to add it to the Url? Here is my code:

SmartImageView image_pic_wall = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_pic_wall);
image_pic_wall.setImageUrl(response.getString("pic_wall"));

Comment: I mean append it to the url as you would any other parameter. e.g. "http://yoursite.com?timestamp=1294782797"